# Thrift C++ server times out, java server doesn't

Tags: c++, thrift

I'm trying to establish communications between a PHP client and a C++ server using the Apache thrift RPC framework. After many hours of fruitless debugging, I built a java server from the same thrift file and got things working. When I run the C++ server, none of my methods get called, and the same client that got a response from the java server throws an exception `Exception: TSocket: timed out reading 4 bytes from localhost:65123` (Even though I've set both the transmit and receive timeouts on the client to 5 seconds.) At least this error is different than the error I get when the server isn't running [`TSocket: Could not connect to localhost:65123 (Connection refused [111])`], so I know the C++ server is at least bound to the port that the client is talking to.

The (working) java server code is:

```
public class Server 
{
    public static void Start(EncabulationGame.Processor<EncabulationInputListener> processor)
    {
        try
        {
            TServerTransport serverTransport = new TServerSocket(65123);
            TServer server = new TSimpleServer(new Args(serverTransport).processor(processor));
            System.out.println("Starting the simple server...");
            server.serve();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Start(new EncabulationGame.Processor<EncabulationInputListener>(new EncabulationInputListener()));
    }

}
```

The (nonworking) C++ server is spawned in a thread separate from the main processing thread of my application. The code looks like:

```
void* ListenerThreadEntryPoint(void* threadStartData)
{
    struct InputListenerThreadStartupData * threadData;
    threadData =  ((struct InputListenerThreadStartupData *) threadStartData);
    int port = threadData->ListnerThreadPort;

    shared_ptr<EncabulationGameHandler> handler(new EncabulationGameHandler(threadData));
    shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new EncabulationGameProcessor(handler));
    shared_ptr<TServerTransport> serverTransport(new TServerSocket(port));
    shared_ptr<TTransportFactory> transportFactory(new TBufferedTransportFactory());
    shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactory());
    TSimpleServer server(processor, serverTransport, transportFactory, protocolFactory);
    server.serve();

    return 0;
}
```

Both the java and the C++ server code snippets are cut-and-pasted from the skeleton code that the thrift compiler generates.

I really can't figure this out. Why is my C++ server not responding to the client? Why are none of the methods in my handler (other than the constructor) being called? I would greatly appreciate any help the community could offer. I'm using the thrift 0.9.0 build.

Here's the code that implements my handler, if it helps:

```
class EncabulationGameHandler : virtual public EncabulationGameIf {
 public:
  EncabulationGameHandler(InputListenerThreadStartupData * threadData) {
    // Your initialization goes here
  }

  int32_t RegisterPlayer() {
    // Your implementation goes here
    printf("RegisterPlayer\n");
  }

  void UnRegisterPlayer(const int32_t playerID) {
    // Your implementation goes here
    printf("UnRegisterPlayer\n");
  }

  bool IsGameRunning() {
    // Your implementation goes here
    printf("IsGameRunning\n");
  }

  int32_t GetPlayerScore(const int32_t playerID) {
    // Your implementation goes here
    printf("GetPlayerScore\n");
  }

  void Bounce(const int32_t playerID) {
    // Your implementation goes here
    printf("Bounce\n");
  }

  void ChangeColor(const int32_t playerID) {
    // Your implementation goes here
    printf("ChangeColor\n");
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, I managed to solve this by using the multithreaded Thrift server model. I never did figure out why the above posted code snippet didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You've not given us enough to go on - so look to the differences and write yourself the simplest C++ server you can that's the same as your standalone java one (eg. runt he C++ server without being in a thread)

The C++ code looks a lot like the auto-gen stuff from the thrift skeleton so I can't see how that could be wrong.